Error running React project after moving from Windows to WSL: "Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\package.json'"
Up until now, my Laravel (backend) and React (frontend) based project was in the Windows directory, but it was going horribly wrong. I copied the whole project to the Linux directory (WSL) and while the backend works fine, React won't run.
I have this error after I try run npm start
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\package.json'

It is true that I can have the frontend on Windows (Documents directory in my case) and the backend in WSL, but firstly - I have the whole project as one repository and no longer want to change that, and secondly - it is not convenient for me.
How can I run React on WSL?
